# C# Application throws “The remote name could not be resolved” exceptions after I change my network

Tags: c#, networking, webclient, vpn

My application throws “The remote name could not be resolved” exceptions after I change my network to corporate network.

Application is written on C# and using WebClient. WebClient instance is created on timer every 3 seconds and gets data from server using UploadValues.

Office network is set up such way that we have few WiFi networks (let us call them A, B, C, D). A – Is the corporate VPN network.

When we run the app, it works well regardless of current network connection. If we change connection between B, C, D app keeps working without problems. If we run app while we are connected to A network, and then switch to B, C or D it still works without problems. But if we start app while we are connect to B,С or D and then switch to A (the corporate VPN one) app throws «The remote name could not be resolved» on every timer tick, and if we switch back to B,C or D, UploadValues starts to work just fine. The only way to make app run properly after switch from B, C, D network to A is to restart the app, (if after restart we switch to B, C, D and back to A app will start crushing again with «The remote name could not be resolved». I tried to access same resource via browser (Chrome, IE 10) and it worked just fine.

I tried to get IP with Dns.GetHostAddresses and it always returns «No such host is known» in A network, but in B, C or D network works just fine. nslookup command returns «Non-existent domain» in A network but works fine in B, C or D. At the same time, I can access resource via Chrome or IE without a problem regardless of the current network.

ipconfig /flushdns, ipconfig /registerdns and ipconfig /renew don’t work.

What is causing this problem? At this point, I am completely lost and I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root of the problem is proxy. It is impossible to reach that service without proxy.  For the unknown reason proxy fails to work when user switches networks.  In order for connection to work you, have to specify Proxy on web client initialization like this:

```
webClient.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the uri is accessable directly from the system, you can use system proxy like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy() })) ...
```